# Custom ExpandableListView во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, expandablelistview

Приветствую.

Мне нужно в один из фрагментов "засунуть" кастомный ExpandableListView.

Fragment3.java:

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {

private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
private ArrayList<Group> ExpListItems;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;

private ArrayList<Group> SetStandardGroups() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, null);

    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    ExpandList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });

    ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
    ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(Fragment3.this.getActivity(), ExpListItems);
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

    String group_names[] = {"1. Английский язык", "2. Физика", "3. География", "4. История",
            "5. Русский язык"};

    String country_names[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

    ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();

    ArrayList<Child> ch_list;

    int size = 1;
    int j = 0;

    for (String group_name : group_names) {
        Group gru = new Group();
        gru.setName(group_name);

        ch_list = new ArrayList<Child>();
        for (; j < size; j++) {
            Child ch = new Child();

            ch.setName(country_names[j]);
            ch_list.add(ch);
        }
        gru.setItems(ch_list);
        list.add(gru);

        size = size + 1;
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

*two.xml*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/snow"
tools:context=".Fragment3">

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/exp_list"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Стектрейс ошибки:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at startandroid.ru.myschool.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:35)
```

35-я строка:

```
ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
```

Что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего ошибка заключается в том, что вы передаете в адаптер `null` вместо массива объектов, т.к. метод `SetStandardGroups` возвращает `null` в качестве коллекции, которая потом передается в адаптер. Для решения проблемы либо заполните либо верните пустую коллекцию из метода `SetStandardGroups`

P.S. при написании кода придерживайтесь стиля описанного [в данном документе](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но я первый раз пишу под андроид. Можете  уточнить что на что поменять? Буду бесконечно признателен.

Comment: @НикитаАвдеев вам надо реализовать метод ```SetStandardGroups``` класса ```Fragment3``` таким образом, чтобы он возвращал ```ArrayList<Group>``` а не ```null```.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых переменные должны называться с **маленькой буквы**

Потому что `ExpandList` и `ExpandList` - это классы, а у класса нет метода `setAdapter`.

**Полный стектрейс ошибки напишите**, т.к. в 35 строке не может быть `NullPointerException` - null может быть только `ExpandList` а вы ранее у него вызываете `setOnItemClickListener`, если б он был null то упал бы тамю

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at startandroid.ru.myschool.ExpandListAdapter.getGroupCount(ExpandListAdapter.java:62)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:397)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:498)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:470)
            at startandroid.ru.myschool.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:35)`

Comment: 62-я строка ExpandListAdapter           `return groups.size();`

Comment: @НикитаАвдеев я так понимаю ExpandListAdapter это ваша реализация? Добавите в свой ответ код.

Answer (score 0):

@anber

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Group> groups;

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);

    tv.setText(child.getName().toString());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv.setText(group.getName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```